# My keys in my returned json are lowercase

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I have 2 projects (nearly) the same. I copy/paste code from the 1st one into the 2nd one. All are ASP.NET MVC solutions. In these projects I retrieve data like this:

```
$.get("/api/mail", { folder: this.params.folder }, self.chosenFolderData);
```

or

```
$.get("/api/vehicle", { category: this.params.category }, self.chosenCategoryData);
```

When I inspect the json data returned from the 1st one I got this:

```
{"Folder":"Inbox","Mails":[{"MailId":4,"Folder":"Inbox","From":"XLN <basia@framehome.xyz>","To":"steve@example.com","Subject"...
```

As you can see my keys are uppercase: Folder, Mails, Folder, Inbox, ...

Here is the same kind of json returned for the 2nd project:

```
{"category":"Car","vehicles":[{"vehicleId":1,"category":"Car","model":"C220","brand":"Mercedes","registration":"AZE-123"}]}
```

All my keys are returned lowercase: category, vehicles, model, brand, ...

Any idea why?

UPDATE_***_*__*_*___**

As requested, here is the Web API action called:

```
    // GET api/Vehicle
    public GetVehiclesViewModel GetVehicles(string category)
    {
        GetVehiclesViewModel viewModel = new GetVehiclesViewModel
        {
            Category = category,
            Vehicles = db.Vehicles.Where(x => x.Category == category).OrderByDescending(u => u.Model).AsEnumerable()
        };

        return viewModel;
    }
```

And here is the viewModel:

```
public class GetVehiclesViewModel
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<VehicleModel> Vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

In my routing for WebAPI I also have this:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

       // Use camel case for JSON data.
       config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Ok right now, I finally discovered that if I remove this:

```
       config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Then my property keys are camel cased. Does anyone can explain me why?

Comment: The casing should match that of the properties of the objects you are serializing unless you've provided your own property name contract resolver in the JSON formatter configuration. Could you show us the vehicle WebAPI action?

Comment: I updated my question to show you my web API action. But it seems ok with that. I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Are you confusing PascalCase with camelCase? By removing the Contract Resolver override, your JSON properties' casing should match your model (Pascal-casing).

Comment: You are right Cory, thank you for correcting me!